# C2556: overloaded function differs only by return type

Tags: c++, constants

I am reading Effective C++ which tells me that 'member functions differing only by their constness can be overloaded'.

The book example is:

```
class TextBlock {
public:
   const char& operator[](std::size_t position) const;
   char& operator[](std::size_t position);

private:
   std::string text;
}
```

My example below, uses a stored pointer.

```
class A  {
public:
   A(int* val) : val_(val) {}

   int* get_message() { return val_; }

   const int* get_message() { return val_; } const;

private:
   int* val_;
};
```

I get:

> error C2556: 'const int *A::get_message(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int *A::get_message(void)'

What is the difference?  Is there any way I can fix the class so I have a const and non-const version of get_message?

Comment: You're confusing the constness of *what the function returns* with the constness of *the function itself*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're putting the `const` qualifier for your `get_message()` function in the wrong place:

```
const int* get_message() const { return val_; }
//                       ^^^^^
//                       Here is where it should be
```

Comment: The extra `;` after `}` should be removed?

Comment: What would the original statement even mean ?

Comment: @StevenMaitlall: Nothing, it is syntactically incorrect. Most likely the OP thought that since `const` appears "before the semicolon" in the example from the book (which only declares the function), it must appear "before the semicolon" even when the function body is inlined inside the class definition. But again, it is a mistake.

Comment: @user619818: Happens to everyone ;)